# How do you sort a query by sum of distinct values?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example if I have a table called sales with the values:

```
╔════════╦═══════╗
║  ITEM  ║ SALES ║
╠════════╬═══════╣
║ record ║     4 ║
║ cd     ║     2 ║
║ cd     ║     5 ║
║ record ║     1 ║
╚════════╩═══════╝
```

How would I write a query to sort by the sum of distinct items so that my output is:

```
╔════════╦════════════╗
║  ITEM  ║ TOTALSALES ║
╠════════╬════════════╣
║ cd     ║          7 ║
║ record ║          5 ║
╚════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your attempt at solving the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`

```
SELECT  item, SUM(sales) totalSales
FROM    sales
GROUP   BY item
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d953c/1)

The output:

```
╔════════╦════════════╗
║  ITEM  ║ TOTALSALES ║
╠════════╬════════════╣
║ cd     ║          7 ║
║ record ║          5 ║
╚════════╩════════════╝
```